# Pricing with-profit/smoothed bonus annuity using Black-Scholes

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, annuity

Would this be possible?

Subsequently, would the pricing of such an annuity be somewhat similar to pricing a lookback option?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the structure?

Comment: It would be a 20 year bonus annuity payable annually in arrears. The starting level would be $200 million p.a. and would be increased by bonuses each year. pri = 4%

Comment: Outside of my expertise. I'm upvoting the question; hope other members can answer.